# C++ boolean usage with a question mark

Tags: c++

What is stored in the variable below?

```
int status = f ? true : false;
```

I tried to use it but cannot tell what is stored in the variable status.

Comment: [Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). `status` would be set to 1 or 0, depending on whether `f` evaluates to `true` or `false` in boolean context.

Comment: Do you know that boolean values are directly convertible to `int`?  `false` is `0` and `true` is `1`.

Comment: @MarkRansom. I do know that. Just that the syntax was confusing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. I understand that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is conditional operator , that it depend upon your `f` for it to be `true` or `false`.
It's like,

```
if(f)
   status =true;
else
  status = false;
```

Comment: Your assertion "you can't save boolean value in a integer type value" is completely false.  The conversion back and forth between `int` and `bool` is well defined.

Comment: @MarkRansom  I have  edited it,